# Faster alternative to DataFrame.iterrows()

Tags: python, pandas

```
data = {'valueA': [-4.213762047, -1.408432067, -0.557258073, -0.213845329, -6.037197312, -0.454789086, -4.816195544,
                   -1.488329919, -4.816195544, -2.301026382, -2.170823094, -5.634475979, -1.189035254, -6.04771587,
                   -5.154490843, -0.667055058, -0.777983333, -0.411221206, -4.213762047, -1.545829201, -4.885603295,
                   -4.816195544, -5.349995991, -0.180029018, -5.348722537, -1.192672691, -1.771607678, -2.261599892,
                   -1.101539885, -1.576736607],
        'valueB': [0.443326304, -5.804335179, -4.45399397, -3.856127364, -5.633162559, 0.08647866, -0.63803755,
                   -0.152266115, -0.211527698, -1.591288764, -0.363876102, -1.824133039, -0.363876102, -0.196084931,
                   -6.038875528, -0.815608686, -3.108092785, -4.213762047, 0.370978551, -4.20366352, -4.213762047,
                   -0.200344922, 0.359609993, -2.130887094, 0.391159162, -3.156335855, -5.446335778, -4.213762047,
                   -4.530705882, -5.227893129]}

dataMean = -0.16243941958211103
dataSTDev = 0.0013394450126162961
dataSet = pd.DataFrame(data)


dataSet['rowValueFlag'] = [
    row['valueA'] + row['valueB'] <= dataMean + 2 * dataSTDev
    for item, row in dataSet.iterrows()
]
```

I use the above loop to go over a DataFrame and check that the sum of two items (`'valueA'` and `'valueB'`) falls at or below 2 standard deviations above the mean of my data. This loop then assigns the `True` and `False` values to a new column in the DataFrame called `'rowValueFlag'`.

My main problem here is that my datasets have 500k + items  this loop is prohibitively slow. Just to make sure everything was actually working I tried cutting my dataset down to only 10k rows and it took about 10 seconds to successfully complete the operation.

I know that using .iterrows() is inefficient, but I don't know how to apply any of the faster alternatives for what I am trying to do. Can anyone provide a more efficient alternative to the approach that I am using?

Thank you so much for the help!! The vectorized code runs much faster, but I was wondering, is it possible to do something like this using and/or statements? For example could I change this iterrows() list comprehension...

```
dataSet['rowValueFlagB'] = [
            (row['valueA'] <= dataMean+ 2 * dataSTDev or row[
                'valueB'] <= dataMean+ 2 * dataSTDev)
            for item, row in dataSet.iterrows()
]
```

into a vectorized operation like this?

```
# Not functional code. Results in a ValueError 
dataSet['rowValueFlagB'] = (dataSet['valueA'] <= dataMean + 2 * dataSTDev) or (dataSet['valueB'] <= dataMean + 2 * dataSTDev)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want speed, use vectorized code:

```py
dataSet["rowValueFlag"] = dataSet["valueA"] + dataSet["valueB"] <= dataMean + 2 * dataSTDev
```

Comment: Was sure that I tested this method and it hadn't worked, but decided to try and it was perfect! Thank you!

Comment: Yes, you just replace the `or` with the `|` operator. `|` is bitwise-or for integers but for series (and numpy arrays), it means "element-wise or"

Comment: thank you so much!! I feel like these were pretty simple questions that I should have known. I really appreciate you taking the time to answer them for me anyways!